# BrowserRouter and HashRouter works for three Routes only

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

### Steps To Reproduce

You can visit [this github project](https://github.com/ashutosh1919/masterPortfolio). On the top of it, you can also see link of the currently deployed version.

Now, in the NavBar, you can see 7 options.
Home, Education, Experience, Projects, Opensource, Blogs, Contact Me.
Among which I have added components of Home, Education, Experience and Opensource.
So, Projects, Blogs and Contact Me will obviously not work because the code corresponding to them has not been added.

But now, the problem is I am routing the components using BrowserRouter (and I have also tried with HashRouter). The Router is working fine on local host using `npm start`. But on `serve -s build`, The Router is able to Route on Home, Education and Opensource. But it is not able to Route to Experience.
I have tried different ways of doing it. But I am not able to solve it.

The Routes are defined in is in `src/container/Main.js` and NavBar is defined in `src/components/header/Header.js`.

### The current behavior

Routing to only 3 nav items.

### The expected behavior

Should Route to 4 items.

Comment: Are you messing with the files/app right now? I was able to navigate to your "/experience" page, but it was blank. Now your home page 404's. After resetting back to your github page and again navigating to app, "/home" loads, but when navigating to "/experience" I see this console error: "ExperienceData is not defined" in `Experience.js:19` I can examine `'../../shared/experience.js'` in the browser though.

Comment: Also, if it helps, I see this error when examining your source `Experience.js` "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" on line 1 for the React import.

Comment: @DrewReese Which files are you talking about? You mentioned `files/app` in your first comment. Are you talking about `App.js`? If yes, then what should I change in it?

Comment: Also, please can you tell me why it is giving Referrence Error even if experience.js file is present

Comment: Sorry, was asking if you were, actively at that moment, messing with your files and/or application code. You had just posted on SO moments before. I suspect the syntax error I see on line 1 when examining the loaded source file is somehow causing the other imports to fail (which would help explain why `ExperienceData` is undefined). My other thought was maybe it was a filename casing issue. I've seen some systems (git for example) and environments struggle when file names change case. No idea if that is what is happening here though.

Comment: @DrewReese, No, I didn't change any code in the main repo. But I am not able to find out why react-dom.production.min.js can't find experience.js file whereas it is finding data files for other tabs.